Shower safety stop stuck / broken
I have an IKEA metallic shower controller. Very similar to their other thermostatic bath/shower mixers, there is a safety "pin" that used to work perfectly fine.
Recently, after having guests over, it became "stuck", resulting in no "safety stoppage", meaning it rotates all the way. This is not due to rust, cartridge or similar issues. I managed to dismantle it: the issue stemmed from a broken plastic (inside), and now the pin is back outside.
However, the remaining issue: the rotation is not aligned, meaning it seems to be like the max is 38 degrees Celsius (used to be the "recommended" max, the one the pin allows to go past). A secondary issue is that if one uses force, you can still rotate too much... although I expect this is due to the half-broken rubber / plastic inside.
It's an old product so the guide / model isn't available online, but the most similar one is this one.
Any suggestions, on how to sort it out? I doubt I can find an alternative piece, i.e. for the interior rubber that held it together.

It hurts when we have to pay 50 dollars for a new fixture when a 5 cent part can repair it.  If it is old enough, then replacing with a new similar fixture is usually faster than trying to find the broken part.  Some parts are universal and a plumbing store might help.

Have you reached out to Ikea?

You mean, IKEA support? In my country, they only have Sales and post-Sales service (e.g. for delivery of wrong products). They do not provide any assembly or troubleshooting service, unless you have just purchased an item... Any this one is 5-6 years old.
